# add other functions to the list in qlpreviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Can you add other functions like email to the list in QLPreviewController's ActionSheet? If so, how? And if not, is there a way to stop the prebuilt one's use in exchange for a simple UIActionSheet?